# Install Ubuntu on an ASUS Q504 laptop

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, asus

I'm looking at purchasing an ASUS Q504 laptop. I want to dual boot either W10 or Ubuntu Mate. The question is will new generation machines allow this? I recall installing mint on my wifes W8 laptop and needed to change to legacy boot. Is there any good way to tell which laptops will install, or is this just like a regular Dual boot install?

- Mike -

Answer (score 0):

For being able to dual boot, I would say that most laptops should be able to boot the live USB in EFI mode so you shouldn't have to change to legacy to dual boot.

The more important part about choosing a laptop to install Ubuntu is hardware support and the ASUS Q504 looks ok. It uses Intel integrated graphics and has an Intel wireless card, which usually work under Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

I have an Asus Transformer Book Flip TP300LA, and it worked fine dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu, you have to turn off secure boot though, and my bios for example didn't have a legacy boot option, so when I installed it using a live usb, it wouldn't boot using the grub boot manager, so I couldn't choose to start it, and could only boot into windows 10. I fixed this by Choosing "UEFI: USB DISK 2.0 PMAP" instead of just "USB DISK 2.0 PMAP"(thats my usb's name) in the boot menu to install ubuntu from, which I accessed by pressing ESC, not sure if it would be the same, since mine is also Asus. My Wifi also didn't work when I booted Ubuntu, so you may need to reinstall your wifi drivers if that also happens to you. Hope that helps :)